# OrientDB distributed mode : data not getting distributed across various nodes

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases, orientdb2.2

I have started an OrientDB Enterprise 2.7 with two nodes. Here is how my setup look.

```
CONFIGURED SERVERS
+----+------+------+-----------+-------------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+
|#   |Name  |Status|Connections|StartedOn          |Binary         |HTTP           |UsedMemory       |FreeMemory       |MaxMemory|
+----+------+------+-----------+-------------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+
|0   |Batman|ONLINE|3          |2016-08-16 15:28:23|10.0.0.195:2424|10.0.0.195:2480|480.98MB (94.49%)|28.02MB (5.51%)  |509.00MB |
|1   |Robin |ONLINE|3          |2016-08-16 15:29:40|10.0.0.37:2424 |10.0.0.37:2480 |403.50MB (79.35%)|105.00MB (20.65%)|508.50MB |
+----+------+------+-----------+-------------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+
orientdb {db=SocialPosts3}> clusters
```

Now I have two Vertex classes User and Notes. With an edge type Posted. All Vertex and Edges have properties. There are also unique index on both the Vertex class.

I started pushing data using Java API :

```
while (retry++ != MAX_RETRY) {
        try {
            properties.put(uniqueIndexname, uniqueIndexValue);
            Iterable<Vertex> resultset = graph.getVertices(className, new String[] { uniqueIndexname },
                    new Object[] { uniqueIndexValue });
            if (resultset != null) {
                vertex = resultset.iterator().hasNext() ? resultset.iterator().next() : null;
            }
            if (vertex == null) {
                vertex = graph.addVertex("class:" + className, properties);
                graph.commit();
                return vertex;
            } else {
                for (String key : properties.keySet()) {
                    vertex.setProperty(key, properties.get(key));
                }
            }
            logger.info("Completed upserting vertex " + uniqueIndexValue);
            graph.commit();
            break;
        } catch (ONeedRetryException ex) {
            logger.warn("Retry for exception - " + uniqueIndexValue);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Can not create vertex - " + e.getMessage());
            graph.rollback();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Similarly for the Notes and edges. 
I populate around 200k user and 3.5M Notes. Now I notice that all the data is going only to one node.

On running "clusters" command I see that all the clusters are created on the same node, and hence all data is present only on one node.

```
|22  |note       |  26|Note     |                 |     75|   Robin    |  [Batman]   |        true        |
|23  |note_1     |  27|Note     |                 |1750902|   Batman   |   [Robin]   |        true        |
|24  |note_2     |  28|Note     |                 |1750789|   Batman   |   [Robin]   |        true        |
|25  |note_3     |  29|Note     |                 |     75|   Robin    |  [Batman]   |        true        |
|26  |posted     |  34|Posted   |                 |      0|   Robin    |  [Batman]   |        true        |
|27  |posted_1   |  35|Posted   |                 |      1|   Robin    |  [Batman]   |        true        |
|28  |posted_2   |  36|Posted   |                 |1739823|   Batman   |   [Robin]   |        true        |
|29  |posted_3   |  37|Posted   |                 |1749250|   Batman   |   [Robin]   |        true        |
|30  |user       |  30|User     |                 | 102059|   Batman   |   [Robin]   |        true        |
|31  |user_1     |  31|User     |                 |      1|   Robin    |  [Batman]   |        true        |
|32  |user_2     |  32|User     |                 |      0|   Robin    |  [Batman]   |        true        |
|33  |user_3     |  33|User     |                 | 102127|   Batman   |   [Robin]   |        true        |
```

I see the CPU of one node is like 99% and other is <1%.

How can I make sure that data is uniformly distributed across all nodes in the cluster?

Update:
Database is propagated to both the nodes. I can login to both the node studio and see the listed database. Also querying any node gives same results, so nodes are in sync.

Server Log from one of the node, and it is almost same on the other node.

```
2016-08-18 19:28:49:668 INFO  [Robin]<-[Batman] Received new status Batman.SocialPosts3=SYNCHRONIZING [OHazelcastPlugin]
2016-08-18 19:28:49:670 INFO  [Robin] Current node started as MASTER for database 'SocialPosts3' [OHazelcastPlugin]
2016-08-18 19:28:49:671 INFO  [Robin] New distributed configuration for database: SocialPosts3 (version=2)

CLUSTER CONFIGURATION (LEGEND: X = Owner, o = Copy)
+--------+-----------+----------+-------------+
|        |           |          |   MASTER    |
|        |           |          |SYNCHRONIZING|
+--------+-----------+----------+-------------+
|CLUSTER |writeQuorum|readQuorum|   Batman    |
+--------+-----------+----------+-------------+
|*       |     1     |    1     |      X      |
|internal|     1     |    1     |             |
+--------+-----------+----------+-------------+

 [OHazelcastPlugin]
2016-08-18 19:28:49:671 INFO  [Robin] Saving distributed configuration file for database 'SocialPosts3' to: /mnt/ebs/orientdb/orientdb-enterprise-2.2.7/databases/SocialPosts3/distributed-config.json [OHazelcastPlugin]
2016-08-18 19:28:49:766 INFO  [Robin] Adding node 'Robin' in partition: SocialPosts3 db=[*] v=3 [ODistributedDatabaseImpl$1]
2016-08-18 19:28:49:767 INFO  [Robin] New distributed configuration for database: SocialPosts3 (version=3)

CLUSTER CONFIGURATION (LEGEND: X = Owner, o = Copy)
+--------+-----------+----------+-------------+-------------+
|        |           |          |   MASTER    |   MASTER    |
|        |           |          |SYNCHRONIZING|SYNCHRONIZING|
+--------+-----------+----------+-------------+-------------+
|CLUSTER |writeQuorum|readQuorum|   Batman    |    Robin    |
+--------+-----------+----------+-------------+-------------+
|*       |     2     |    1     |      X      |      o      |
|internal|     2     |    1     |             |             |
+--------+-----------+----------+-------------+-------------+

 [OHazelcastPlugin]
2016-08-18 19:28:49:767 INFO  [Robin] Saving distributed configuration file for database 'SocialPosts3' to: /mnt/ebs/orientdb/orientdb-enterprise-2.2.7/databases/SocialPosts3/distributed-config.json [OHazelcastPlugin]
2016-08-18 19:28:49:769 WARNI [Robin]->[[Batman]] Requesting deploy of database 'SocialPosts3' on local server... [OHazelcastPlugin]
2016-08-18 19:28:52:192 INFO  [Robin]<-[Batman] Copying remote database 'SocialPosts3' to: /tmp/orientdb/install_SocialPosts3.zip [OHazelcastPlugin]
2016-08-18 19:28:52:193 INFO  [Robin]<-[Batman] Installing database 'SocialPosts3' to: /mnt/ebs/orientdb/orientdb-enterprise-2.2.7/databases/SocialPosts3... [OHazelcastPlugin]
2016-08-18 19:28:52:193 INFO  [Robin] - writing chunk #1 offset=0 size=43.38KB [OHazelcastPlugin]
2016-08-18 19:28:52:194 INFO  [Robin] Database copied correctly, size=43.38KB [ODistributedAbstractPlugin$3]
2016-08-18 19:28:52:279 WARNI {db=SocialPosts3} Storage 'SocialPosts3' was not closed properly. Will try to recover from write ahead log [OEnterpriseLocalPaginatedStorage]
2016-08-18 19:28:52:279 SEVER {db=SocialPosts3} Restore is not possible because write ahead log is empty. [OEnterpriseLocalPaginatedStorage]
2016-08-18 19:28:52:279 INFO  {db=SocialPosts3} Storage data recover was completed [OEnterpriseLocalPaginatedStorage]
2016-08-18 19:28:52:294 INFO  {db=SocialPosts3} [Robin] Installed database 'SocialPosts3' (LSN=OLogSequenceNumber{segment=0, position=24}) [OHazelcastPlugin]
2016-08-18 19:28:52:304 INFO  [Robin] Reassigning cluster ownership for database SocialPosts3 [OHazelcastPlugin]
2016-08-18 19:28:52:305 INFO  [Robin] New distributed configuration for database: SocialPosts3 (version=3)

CLUSTER CONFIGURATION (LEGEND: X = Owner, o = Copy)
+--------+----+-----------+----------+-------------+-------------+
|        |    |           |          |   MASTER    |   MASTER    |
|        |    |           |          |SYNCHRONIZING|SYNCHRONIZING|
+--------+----+-----------+----------+-------------+-------------+
|CLUSTER |  id|writeQuorum|readQuorum|   Batman    |    Robin    |
+--------+----+-----------+----------+-------------+-------------+
|*       |    |     2     |    1     |      X      |      o      |
|internal|   0|     2     |    1     |             |             |
+--------+----+-----------+----------+-------------+-------------+

 [OHazelcastPlugin]
2016-08-18 19:28:52:305 INFO  [Robin] Distributed servers status:

+------+------+------------------------------------+-----+-------------------+---------------+---------------+--------------------------+
|Name  |Status|Databases                           |Conns|StartedOn          |Binary         |HTTP           |UsedMemory                |
+------+------+------------------------------------+-----+-------------------+---------------+---------------+--------------------------+
|Batman|ONLINE|GoodBoys=ONLINE (MASTER)            |5    |2016-08-16 15:28:23|10.0.0.195:2424|10.0.0.195:2480|426.47MB/509.00MB (83.79%)|
|      |      |SocialPosts=ONLINE (MASTER)         |     |                   |               |               |                          |
|      |      |GratefulDeadConcerts=ONLINE (MASTER)|     |                   |               |               |                          |
|Robin*|ONLINE|GoodBoys=ONLINE (MASTER)            |3    |2016-08-16 15:29:40|10.0.0.37:2424 |10.0.0.37:2480 |353.77MB/507.50MB (69.71%)|
|      |      |SocialPosts=ONLINE (MASTER)         |     |                   |               |               |                          |
|      |      |GratefulDeadConcerts=ONLINE (MASTER)|     |                   |               |               |                          |
|      |      |SocialPosts3=SYNCHRONIZING (MASTER) |     |                   |               |               |                          |
|      |      |SocialPosts2=ONLINE (MASTER)        |     |                   |               |               |                          |
+------+------+------------------------------------+-----+-------------------+---------------+---------------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: Could you please attach the logs of both servers when the database has been propagated on both nodes?

Comment: added the logs in the post.

Comment: I can see that Robin is asking to Batman the database and Batman sent it back `2016-08-18 19:28:49:769 WARNI [Robin]->[[Batman]] Requesting deploy of database 'SocialPosts3' on local server... [OHazelcastPlugin]
`, but in the final table SocialPosts3 is not on Batman server, so how is possible it sent the database? How many database do you need? I suggest you to remove what you don't need so it's simple to understand what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That is what I was trying to do, delete all unused table. Finally I deleted all tables and created a brand new table. Added one more node to the cluster. However the data distribution is same , and so is the CPU, only one node is have 100% and rest two are idle.